# How to unit test classes with bean validation? (Java EE)

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, maven, bean-validation

I'm unit testing some classes annotated with jsr303 constraints, but I can't find a proper maven dependency for `javax.validation.Validation` in order to create the `ValidatorFactory` used in my tests. And the weird thing is I've got that problem only with the `Validation`class. The constraints and the validation factory itself resolve just fine.

NetBeans (7.3) gives me a "Java EE API is missing on project classpath" message for every dependency I've tried so far (both hibernate-validator and validation-api).
Here's some of the pom (including both dependencies):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to declare the `validation-api` test dependency before the `javaee-api`, otherwise Maven would try to use it for tests, wich is not possible. Declaring it after does not override the broader scope dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try changing validation-api's groupID to javax.validation

[Reference](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final)

Comment: My bad. That was due to some testing and I forgot to change it back. Using javax.validation still doesn't fix it.

Comment: Well, I've just tested building a new mvn project in NB 7.3 with all your dependencies (and an additional repo for EclipseLink), and using javax.validation.Validation in a source file compiles, I've got no build errors at all.

Comment: Odd. That source file was it in a test package?

Comment: Never mind, I've figured it out. Turns out I must declare the validation-api test dependency before the javaee-api or maven will try to use it for tests, wich is not possible. Thanks.